# iOS MapView cannot cooperate with GPS service

Tags: ios, swift, gps, mkmapview

I have faced an issue that I would like to fetch the user's location via GPS. However, I cannot cooperate Map view with it but only GPS is good. I would like to have the location and make it as an annotation on the map view.
Following is the code in Swift.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBOutlet weak var LocateBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func Locate(sender: UIButton) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            println(2)
            if (error != nil) {
                println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                println(3)
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            } else {
                println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })
    }


    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark?) {
        if let containsPlacemark = placemark {
            //stop updating location to save battery life
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let locality = (containsPlacemark.locality != nil) ? containsPlacemark.locality : ""
            let postalCode = (containsPlacemark.postalCode != nil) ? containsPlacemark.postalCode : ""
            let administrativeArea = (containsPlacemark.administrativeArea != nil) ? containsPlacemark.administrativeArea : ""
            let country = (containsPlacemark.country != nil) ? containsPlacemark.country : ""
            let locations = Locations()
            var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()


            for dictionary in locations {


                let coordinate = containsPlacemark.location.coordinate
                let first = dictionary["firstName"] as! String
                let last = dictionary["lastName"] as! String
                let mediaURL = dictionary["mediaURL"] as! String

                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = coordinate
                annotation.title = "\(first) \(last)"
                annotation.subtitle = mediaURL

                annotations.append(annotation)
            }
            println(annotations)
            self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
        }

    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
            let reusedId = "pin"

            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reusedId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reusedId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.pinColor = .Red
            pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton

        } else {
            pinView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return pinView
    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

        if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
            app.openURL(NSURL(string: annotationView.annotation.subtitle!)!)
        }
    }

    func Locations() -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
        return [
            [
                "createdAt" : "2015-7-3T21:50:00",
                "firstName" : "Joe",
                "lastName" : "Li",
                "latitude" : 28.1461248,
                "longitude" : -82.75676799999999,
                "mapString" : "Tarpon Springs, FL",
                "mediaURL" : "www.linkedin.com/in/jessicauelmen/en",
                "objectId" : "kj18GEaWD8",
                "uniqueKey" : 872458750,
                "updatedAt" : "2015-7-4T21:00:00"
             ]
        ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Tutorial [Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Maps_on_iOS_8_with_Swift,_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class):

Try This:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)        
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```